# blockexplorer is not fully synced

Tags: altcoin

I am working with a cryptocurrency which is a fork of bitcoin. In my blockexplorer it shows 91% synced and I cant see any latest blocks.

Answer (score -1):

Does the GUI of the daemon show that you are connected to inbound peers?

If it does, you may have to do a re-sync of the blockchain from scratch. It's happened to me before.

Not sure which crypto you're using, but I'd try backing up your wallet.dat files, you can save a copy of the blockchain database as well if it's huge and restore it later just in case.

But back up your wallet files, then do a fresh install, re-sync the blockchain, and see if it gets to sync status. Then open your wallet files.

Comment: Hello 

Thank you so much for the reply. Please check the link for the status [link]https://www.screencast.com/t/kBiWZ1yTQvt [/link]

Its says 91% synced and there is no other updates. This is fork of bitcoin. Where can I check any log for some possible issues?